# NMock - how to say expect 'any value' on these params? Or should I not do this?

Tags: unit-testing, nmock, nmock2

I have a quick question that I could not figure out in the docs about NMock2.0.

I have a function called Save() that I want to mock out. This takes a string ID as parameter and a decimal as value..

I know I can write this to make sure that Save() gets called with 2 specific values:

```
    Expect.Once.On(dao) _
    .Method("Save").With(New Object() {"foo", 1})
```

But this only passes if "foo" and 1 are passed. I do have control of the value "foo", but for the second value, I don't know what it will be; or I don't care about testing what it's value will be at least in this specific test.

I know I can write:

```
    Expect.Once.On(dao) _
    .Method("Save").WithAnyArguments()
```

But this will allow me to pass any arguements; so if Save interface changes and later takes 5 parameters, my test will still pass.

How can I make sure it only takes the 2 params, with their proper types?

Perhaps more importantly - is writing a unit test like this too brittle? Maybe I should code it to expect any params, so that each time I refactor I do not have to come back and change that line? I have found that my test cases which use lots of mocks are very brittle and anytime I refactor I have to change them... Maybe I am mis-using mocks here? Still pretty new to this stuff, so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Is.TypeOf()` matcher to match a specific type without regard for its value. You want something like:

```
Expect.Once.On(dao).Method("Save").With(Is.TypeOf(typeof(string)));
```

As for whether it's reasonable or not, I'd say this is fine in the general case if you're trying to verify that a method can deal with parameters of its specified input types. For example, say you pass in a `Car` to a method that expects a `Vehicle`; it will be useful to make sure that the method can handle derived types correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does this mean that my 'dao' object is now considered a mock, because I am asserting against it?

In that case, how do I make a 'stub' with NMock so that it will just make the code compile with no asserts? Do I just do .WithAnyParameters()? Or this would still be considered a mock because of VerifyExpectationsHasBeenMet() will fail if the function isn't called? If so, how to make a 'stub' as defined by Fowler?

Comment: @dferraro to stubs just replace `Expect.Once` with `Stub` so your stubbed call will not count against VerifyExpectationsHasBeenMet.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a simple class:

```
class DontCare
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

Expect.Once.On(dao).Method("Save").With(new DontCare());
```